# simple multithreading error in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am fairly new to the C language. I have written a piece of code which creates two thread to calculate two different results. the code actually works but the compiling is showing errors and I want to know what is actually the error. can anyone help me? I am new to C, so I guess it might be a very silly mistake...

Errors:

```
q3.c: In function ‘main’:
q3.c:63:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from q3.c:5:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘double * (*)(void *)’
q3.c:64:9: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from q3.c:5:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘double * (*)(void *)’
```

The code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.1415

int i, x, n;

double *sin_x(void* dimension);
double *cos_x(void* dimension);
int fact(int);
struct data
{
  int ang_deg;
  int no_of_terms;
};

int fact(int num)
{
  int f = 0;

  if (num == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    f = num * fact(num - 1);

  return f;
}

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
  printf("\nEnter x and n:\t");
  scanf("%d %d", &x, &n);

  struct data
  {
    int ang_rad;
    int no_of_terms;
  };

  struct data dimension;  // automatic allocation, all fields placed on stack

  dimension.ang_rad = x;
  dimension.no_of_terms = n;

  pthread_t thrd1, thrd2;
  int thret1, thret2;

  thret1 = pthread_create(&thrd1, NULL, sin_x, (void *) &dimension);
  thret2 = pthread_create(&thrd2, NULL, cos_x, (void *) &dimension);

  pthread_join(thrd1, NULL );
  pthread_join(thrd2, NULL );

  //printf("\nthret1 = %d\n", thret1);
  //printf("thret2 = %d\n", thret2);
  sleep(5);
  printf("Parent Thread exiting...\n");

  exit(1);

  return 0;
}

double *sin_x(void* dimension)
{
  struct data* dim = (struct data*) dimension;
  int ang_deg = dim->ang_deg;
  int no_of_terms = dim->no_of_terms;

  //int ang_deg, int no_of_terms
  int term, j;
  double value = 0.0, ang_rad = 0.0;
  ang_rad = (double) ang_deg * PI / 180;

  for (term = 1, j = 2; term < no_of_terms * 2; term += 2, j++)
  {
    value += (double) pow(-1.0, j) * pow(ang_rad, term) / fact(term);
  }

  printf("\nSin(%d) = %f", ang_deg, value);
  double *a = &value;

  return a;
}

double *cos_x(void* dimension)
{
  struct data* dim = (struct data*) dimension;
  int ang_deg = dim->ang_deg;
  int no_of_terms = dim->no_of_terms;

  int term, j;
  double value = 1.0, ang_rad = 0.0;
  ang_rad = (double) ang_deg * PI / 180;

  for (term = 2, j = 1; term <= no_of_terms; term += 2, j++)
  {
    value += (double) pow(-1.0, j) * pow(ang_rad, term) / fact(term);
  }

  printf("\nCos(%d) = %f", ang_deg, value);
  double *a = &value;

  return a;
}
```

Comment: `int main (int argc, char argv[])` is not valid!

Comment: i should just remove the arguments from main? i don't understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes:

- Replaced `sleep()` with `pthread_exit()`. Sleep is a poor idea for synchronization.
- Corrected `main()`'s parameters. It should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char**argv)` or equivalent.
- Removed unnecessary struct inside `main()`.
- Changed the return type of `fact()` to `size_t`, which would allow you to calculate more factorials than possible with `int` type.
- Rewrote the factorial function to use memoization. This is more efficient way of calculating factorial since you don't need to recalculate the previous factorials that have been computed already. The array size is 64K which you can change. As it currently stands, it can calculate 
  first 64K factorials.
- You should add eror checking for `pthread_` functions.
- Removed `pthread_join()` calls since `main()` thread exits. The process will exit naturally once the last thread exits.
- Removed the thread values since you are not using them. If you do want to know computed values, you can add another member to struct dimension and store the result in that. This method would allow to return complex value from thread functions.

--

Here's a fully functional code with all the above changes done. For more info, read [`pthread_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) and manuals of other functions.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.1415

int i, x, n;
void *sin_x( void* dimension );
void *cos_x( void* dimension );
size_t fact( int );

size_t tab[64*1024] = {1};
struct data
            {
                int ang_deg;
                int no_of_terms;
            };  

size_t fact( int num )
{
      size_t f = 0;

      if ( tab[num]) return tab[num];

      f = num * fact( num - 1 );
      tab[num] = f;

      return f;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{ 
        printf( "\nEnter x and n:\t" );
        scanf( "%d %d", &x, &n );

        struct data dimension;  // automatic allocation, all fields placed on stack

        dimension.ang_deg = x;
        dimension.no_of_terms= n;

        pthread_t thrd1, thrd2;
        int thret1, thret2; 

        thret1 = pthread_create(&thrd1, NULL, sin_x, &dimension);
        thret2 = pthread_create(&thrd2, NULL, cos_x, &dimension);   

        printf("Parent Thread exiting...\n");
        pthread_exit(0);
}

void *sin_x( void* dimension )
{
    struct data* dim = dimension;
    int ang_deg = dim->ang_deg;
    int no_of_terms = dim->no_of_terms;
    int term, j;
    double value = 0.0, ang_rad = 0.0;
    ang_rad = ( double ) ang_deg * PI / 180;

    for ( term = 1, j = 2;term < no_of_terms*2;term += 2, j++ )
        {
            value += ( double ) pow( -1.0, j ) * pow( ang_rad, term ) / fact( term );
        }
    printf("\nSin(%d) = %f", ang_deg, value);
    return 0;
}

void *cos_x( void* dimension )
{
    struct data* dim = dimension;
    int ang_deg = dim->ang_deg;
    int no_of_terms = dim->no_of_terms;
    int term, j;
    double value = 1.0, ang_rad = 0.0;
    ang_rad = ( double ) ang_deg * PI / 180;

    for ( term = 2, j = 1;term <= no_of_terms;term += 2, j++ )
        {
            value += ( double ) pow( -1.0, j ) * pow( ang_rad, term ) / fact( term );
        }

    printf("\nCos(%d) = %f", ang_deg, value);
    double *a = &value;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works...no errors this time!! but why is it necessary to cast this parameter?

Comment: @user2228135 in order to tell the compiler what kind of data we are dealing with

Comment: Casting is bad idea. This is not a portable solution. Make the thread functions return what the ought to return which is `void`-pointer. Everything else invokes undefined behaviour. Also in C there is not need to cast the 4th argument to `pthread_create()` to `void*`.

Comment: The cast you introduced (`struct data* dim = (struct data*)dimension;`) in the update isn't wrong, but still not needed.

Comment: @alk Sure, it's not needed. But if you cared to read the question properly, you would have noticed that I didn't "introduce" it.

Comment: Indeed, you didn't, sorry! Please excuse the imputation.

Comment: @alk You know, despite my best efforts, I can't find every little fault in the code especially if it would _never_ make any difference whether the cast is there or not. I just edited it out just to save you the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

It's not errors, but warnings.

Your functions are :

```
double *sin_x (void *dimension);
double *cos_x (void *dimension);
```

Since a function's name is a pointer to the function, the type of `sin_x` is : `double * (*) (void *)` (literally : a pointer to a function taking a `void*` as argument and returning a `double *`), same for `cos_x`.

But `pthread_create` is waiting for the type `void * (*) (void *)` (a pointer to a function taking `void*` as argument and returning `void*`).

Since `double*` and `void*` are both pointers, they have the same size (8 bytes on a 64b for example), so the compiler just warn you.